# trace of $(A^4-A^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be a $2\times 2 $ complex matrix with $\det A=-6$ and trace(A)=1, I need to find the trace of $(A^4-A^3)$

so $A^2-A-6I=0$ so $(A^4-A^3)=6A^2$
how to proceed next?

Comment: Why not use the characteristic polynomial/Caylay-Hamilton once again?

Comment: after that stage I was trying to calculate $trace (6A^2)$, but did not know how

Comment: Since $A^2-A-6I=0$, $\mathrm{tr} (6A^2)=6\cdot\mathrm{tr}(A+6I)$.

Comment: @Landscape Thank you, did not notice that.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: For $2\times 2$ matrices you have: $2\det A = (\operatorname{tr} A)^2 - \operatorname{tr} (A^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues; eigenvalues of $A^2$ are squared eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 6):

$A$ is conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$, so $A^4-A^3$ is conjugate to $\begin{pmatrix} 54 & 0 \\ 0 & 24\end{pmatrix}$ and thus has trace $78$.